# How to i get word embeddings for out of vocabulary words using a transformer model?

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers, transformer-model, huggingface-tokenizers, oov

When i tried to get word embeddings of a sentence using bio_clinical bert, for a sentence of 8 words i am getting 11 token ids(+start and end) because "embeddings" is an out of vocabulary word/token, that is being split into `em`, `bed` ,`ding`, `s`.

I would like to know if there is any aggregation strategies available that make sense apart from doing a mean of these vectors.

```py
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModel
# download and load model
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("emilyalsentzer/Bio_ClinicalBERT")
model = AutoModel.from_pretrained("emilyalsentzer/Bio_ClinicalBERT")

sentences = ['This framework generates embeddings for each input sentence']


#Tokenize sentences
encoded_input = tokenizer(sentences, padding=True, truncation=True, max_length=128, return_tensors='pt')


#Compute token embeddings
with torch.no_grad():
    model_output = model(**encoded_input)

print(encoded_input['input_ids'].shape)
```

Output:
`torch.Size([1, 13])`

```py
for token in encoded_input['input_ids'][0]:
      print(tokenizer.decode([token]))
```

Output:

```
[CLS]
this
framework
generates
em
##bed
##ding
##s
for
each
input
sentence
[SEP]
```

Answer (score 4):

To my knowledge, mean aggregation is the most commonly used tool here, and in fact there is even scientific literature, empirically showing that it works well:
[Generalizing Word Embeddings using Bag of Subwords](https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/D18-1059.pdf) by Zhao, Mudgal and Liang. Formula 1 is describing exactly what you are proposing as well.

The one alternative that you could theoretically employ is something like a mean aggregate *over the entire input*, essentially making a "context prediction" over all words (potentially except "`embeddings`"), therefore emulating something similar to the `[MASK]`ing during training of the transformer models. But this is just a suggestion from me without any backup of scientific evidence that it works (for better or worse).